# How can I use model (DB) data in djangoCMS, without creating views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I think my question is pretty clear:

I am interested in finding out some ways of using model (DB) data without creating views.

I have already created a website using djangocms and now I would like to develop a little blog.

I am aware of [this project](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog) but this is not as straight forward as I'd need ( it is pretty complex for my purpose ).

For example, in the first place, I would like to know if there's any possibility to create a basic template in which I will be able to display the users(their names) directly from the database.

Comment: This is actually a good question. I'd also like to see a nice answer for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) which essentially is a function which returns a dictionary & it's added to **every** request context.

For example, I have a model which provides information for the site as a whole, like social links, a name etc. Take a look;

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site

from .models import SiteSettings


def site_settings(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    try:
        settings = SiteSettings.objects.get(site_id=current_site.id)

    except SiteSettings.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        settings = SiteSettings.objects.filter(
            site_id=current_site.id
        ).order_by('id')[0]

    except SiteSettings.DoesNotExist:
        return {
            'SITE_SITE_NAME': None,
            'SITE_SHORT_NAME': None,
        }

    # SiteSettings object exists, so assign the attributes you want, to context 
    # variables returned by the context processor for all views.
    data = {
        'SITE_SITE_NAME': settings.site_name,
        'SITE_SHORT_NAME': settings.short_name,
    }

    return data
```

So by doing that you can use things like `{{ SITE_SHORT_NAME }}` in any template, and this obviously makes any information you hold in a table available via one of these processors. Just make sure you create necessary `DoesNotExist` exceptions when doing this with models.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have one question though: "will this allow me to avoid the usage of views ?". Can you also put some comments next to your code ? Thank @marksweb

Comment: 'To avoid the usage of views' sounds a little confusing. Where exactly do you want to use this data? I assumed you meant you wanted data available without specifically creating it within a view.

Comment: You're correct. That's what I meant. More, what do you think about `render_model`. Would that also fit my need ?

Comment: Ah I see, in terms of specifics from CMS you can always include that template tag to get model attributes, but you still need to pass a model instance in to the view for that to work. See the docs; http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/templatetags.html#std:templatetag-render_model

Answer (score 3):

In Django, you basically *can't* get data from a model to a template without a view that puts it there. That's the whole point of views.

You don't necessarily have to create a `views.py` file, because there might be other mechanisms that you can make use of, such as django CMS's plugin system.

I don't understand what connection your question has to developing a weblog though.

Comment: can you improve your answer so that it shows how can I use a django CMS plugin for displaying the users directly from database ? Or at least reccommend some plugins.